# Online mysql database connectivity with sencha?

Tags: android, iphone, mysql, database, extjs

I have made an app with sencha
i have a page where i want a people to be able to check the status of their request
so basically if they type the id they get the status 
this status is fetched from an online mysql database which is controlled by a php page online
so the database will be only id and status
if its easier with phone gap i don't mind switching
pleeeeaaaasssseee help :(

Guys i have been trying this for a while and never found a specific answer ... please help !!
Its very urgent !! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you're asking how to create the PHP script, or how to access the PHP script from Sencha.

For the former, you'd simply do the usual `mysql_connect()` to connect to your database and then `$_GET["id"]` to retrieve the id you'd given as an argument in the URL, assuming you want to pass the ID using GET and you want the "service" to be RESTful. The value returned by `$_GET["id"]` could then be used in your `mysql_query()` statement, the result of which could be echoed out.

For the latter, again assuming you want to do it in RESTful way, you'd access `www.domainforyourphpscript.com/path/to/your/php/script.php?id=31`, where 31 is an example ID. The isn't specific to Sencha though, so you could quite easily access it using something like JQuery too, or even just by entering the URL into a web browser.

Does this answer your question? I can elaborate on a specific part if you need more detailed information.

Comment: Hey thanx a lot for answering :) ok so i have two doubts .... Can i use php in sencha application ? And secondly i don't want local storage ..... I just want a way for my sencha application to select the queried data from an online server

Comment: I don't know what your knowledge of PHP is like, but PHP is used on the server only, not the client-side. So Sencha uses JavaScript to get the data from the online server which is what uses the PHP. Using this method, no data will be stored locally, at least not permanently.

Comment: Ya so if i post my form to a server side php made that i hav n collect the results how do i return the results to the app :/ i'm sorry for askin such stupid questions .... Also using javascript is like persistence.js right ?

Comment: It's sort of up to you. You can return them in JSON format, or just as plain text. Either way, if you just do something like `echo(result)`, whatever you echo will be returned to the client.

I've not used persistence.js before so I can't comment on how similar it is to Sencha, but they're both written in JavaScript so yes you will be using the same syntax. Sencha itself is quite a large and complex framework however, and does take a while to learn. If this is only a small application, it may be worth using JQuery and JQuery mobile instead, as it's a lot more lightweight and quicker to learn.